# HTML 5 application cache and codeigniter php framework

Tags: html, codeigniter-2

I am creating a php codeigniter based administration backend which will be accessed only in google chrome browser. So, I thought of using HTML 5 application cache to reduce the loading time of images and js. But I have a problem now.

When I use  in the head of the page, needed to use the application cache, my php page is also being cached. So, when I add a record in the application db, that new record is not shown on the listing page. Only old records are shown. This means chrome caches the html of the page also.

How can I prevent chrome from caching the html? in the NETWORK section of cache manifet I have * as an entry. If I go about adding the names of the pages which should never cache, then how can I add the pages for codeigniter?

For eg. http://staging.me.com/admin/login .How can I tell the manifest not to cache it?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Gaurav

Comment: I suggest you cache HTML and load data via separate Javascript AJAX GET request.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa not possible. the full app is already made.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the cache is from Chrome? Maybe you are using the cache function in CodeIgniter? The cache would need to be expired or disabled on CI first.  Just double checking as you didn't state if you are using it in both places.

However my first thought for this interface is WHY are you prematurely optimizing / caching images? Do you really need to spend so much time to get this working? I am willing to bet that ultimately you are getting a micro boost in load vs non cache.

I would re-evaluate your need for chrome caching first before proceeding.

Comment: no, i am not using ci cache. i tripple checked it. the reason i want to use html 5 cache is performance boost. there are 20,000 images which needs to be loaded. it is just a very data heavy app. so, i thought it would be a value added feature. also, the js is whopping 1 mb after using google closure. when i use html 5 cache the pages load blazingly fast. but alas!